# Raq SQL in sqlAlchemy appearing to format year wrong

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to fix a bug where data from my database is not being grouped correctly and was wondering if there was a simple fix as I'm not a SQL master.

We are trying to group a count of records around specific dates. The problem that rears it's head only because we are on the new year and that new year ends the week.  What happens is one of the dates instead of coming up as 12/27/2020, it must get the year of the last day of the week and turns it into 12/27/2021. All jokes about how we all wished it was 2021 already at that point, it's a odd error and I'm unsure how to fix it.

Here is the offending block of Python that I think contains the problem:

```
date = sa.literal_column("to_date(concat(extract(year from {}.created_at),extract(week from {}.created_at)), 'yyyyww')".format(metric_class.__table__,metric_class.__table__))
if 'date_group' in request_args:
    group_classname = "".join([part.title() for part in request_args['date_group'].split("_")])
    group_class = expand_classes[group_classname]
    date = sa.literal_column("to_date(concat(extract(year from {}.created_at),extract(week from {}.created_at)), 'yyyyww')".format(group_class.__table__,group_class.__table__))
```

EDIT: adding in requested information

metric_class and group class: Are just a references to one of our many tables clases. They all contain a id (primary key) and a created_at (date).

A example acttual query generated in my environment:

```
SELECT to_date(concat(extract(year from users.created_at),extract(week from users.created_at)), 'yyyyww'), count(users.id) AS count_1  
FROM users
WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL AND users.company_id = '762976f4-8e19-4f1a-a0ef-b205fb8f68f2' AND
users.created_at > '1/21/2020' AND users.role = 2 GROUP BY 
to_date(concat(extract(year from users.created_at),extract(week from users.created_at)), 'yyyyww') ORDER BY to_date(concat(extract(year from users.created_at),extract(week from users.created_at)), 'yyyyww') DESC LIMIT 50;
```

I can't show you the acttual erroring data as it's in a production environment I do not have access to, but here is a example of what you might see edited from my data:

```
 to_date   | count_1 
------------+---------
 2021-12-28 |       1
 2020-12-16 |       2
 2020-12-02 |       1
 2020-11-25 |      12
 2020-11-18 |       3
 2020-11-04 |       2
 2020-05-27 |       2
 2020-04-01 |       3
 2020-03-25 |       1
 2020-03-18 |       1
 2020-02-12 |       1
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Can you post the relevant parts of `metric_class` and `group_class`. And where are you using the `literal_column` `date`. And some sample data.

Comment: I added what I think is relavent information.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Postgresql is what we use.

Comment: What happens if you use `.group_by(func.date_trunc('week', Users.created_at))` instead of the literal column?

Comment: Modified it a bit to not error: `if group_class:
        query = query.group_by(func.date_trunc('week', metric_class.created_at), group_class.created_at, metric_class.created_at)
    else:
        query = query.group_by(func.date_trunc('week', metric_class.created_at), metric_class.created_at)`  Printing the returned data I got about 29 rows instead of the expected 10.  Some of the data looked like this: `0: {count: 1, group: "Fri, 15 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT"}
1: {count: 1, group: "Wed, 16 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT"}
2: {...}`

Comment: Why are you adding the order by `created_at` next to `date_trunc`?

Comment: I get an error of the likes of: 'column "users.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'

Comment: Maybe you also need to add `order_by` with the same argument.

Comment: Well no luck really so far. But this might be the right direction. I will play around with it and see if I can come up with the right combination

Comment: Acttually I'm finding this isn't the right path.  I need to change this little bit of raw SQL: "to_date(concat(extract(year from {}.created_at),extract(week from {}.created_at)), 'yyyyww')"  in the two places it is used to somehow overcome how extract works.  When given a date like '1-1-2021' which is at the end of the last week of the year, it extracts that year instead of 2020. I need to be able to tell it to use 2020 not the 2021 it's grabbing from the actual date or possibly tell it to use the first week of 2021 not the last of 2020

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227678/discussion-between-rfkortekaas-and-j-finn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and playing around with what rfkortekaas was talking about, I found a simple fix.

I changed the two lines of:

```
date = sa.literal_column("to_date(concat(extract(year from {}.created_at),extract(week from {}.created_at)), 'yyyyww')".format(metric_class.__table__,metric_class.__table__))
```

to:

```
 date = sa.literal_column("date_trunc('week',{}.created_at)".format(metric_class.__table__))
```

date_trunc is the way to get the start of the week